# PySpark - mean function

Tags: pyspark

I have a problem with mean function in PySpark.
I tried applying mean function as follow

```
*mse = rdd.map(lambda x : (x[2]-predictedRating(x,P,Q))**2).mean()*
```

Where `preditecRating` is a *function* I declared before, but it never ends and tells me that it was stuck at `mean()`. I don't understand why it doesn't work?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please add more information about your data , predictedRating.

Comment: Add more information, like what is PredictedRating function?